# ImageField is not defined

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I'm building a personal photography site using Django. I'm working on the models.py. My app is called "photoViewer", the site is called "photoSite". However, when I run makemigrations, I'm getting:

`NameError: name 'ImageField' is not defined`

I have 3 images stored in `"photoSite\photoViewer\static\photoViewer\images"` locally, that I'd like to display on my completed site.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Photo (models.Model):
    photo_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo_img = ImageField(upload_to = "images/") #Error here
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.photo_title
class Album (models.Model):
    photos= models.ManyToManyField(Photo)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.album_title
```

settings.py:

```
...
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'static').replace('\\','/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have a syntax issue...

```
photo_img = ImageField(upload_to = "images/")
```

Should be...

```
photo_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "images/")
```